# Reuse Enhanced For Loop Different Class Types

Tags: java, generics, for-loop

I hope this is not a repeat as I couldn't find anything answering exactly what I was looking for..
I have a chunk of code that is repeated in populating a large map. 
The only difference between the different chunks of code is the class that is being looped through.

Example:

```
for (SomeClass class : SomeClassList) {
         // Repeated code here.
    }
for (AnotherClass aClass : AnotherClassList) {
         // Repeated code here.
    }
for (AndAnotherClass fClass : AndAnotherClassList) {
         // Repeated code here.
    } 
etc...
```

All of these classes share two methods, `getXYZ()` and `setXYZ()`. I have tried to use generics but have failed multiple types. I would like to create a method where I can pass in different lists of varying classes preform the same code on the different lists. 
 Something like this:

```
public void anyList(List<?> list){
   for(classOfList item: list){
      //code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're your classes, put `getXYZ` and `setXYZ` in an interface they all implement (directly, or from a base class, etc.), and then use the interface as your type in the enhanced `for` loop.

```
interface HasXYZ {
    void setXYZ(XYZType xyz);
    XYZType getXYZ();
}

class SomeClass implements HasXYZ {
    // ...
}

class AnotherClass implements HasXYZ {
    // ...
}

class AndAnotherClass implements HasXYZ {
    // ...
}
```

Then your `anyList`:

```
public void anyList(List<HasXYZ> list){
    for (HasXYZ item : list){
        // code here
    }
}
```

Then:

```
anyList(someClassList);
anyList(anotherClassList);
anyList(andAnotherClassList);
```

Comment: Do you really need to combine the list? You could just have a method that you invoke for each of the lists.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Yeah, definitely better. AND the op did mention doing that, as well, so where was I? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface (SomeInterface) that SomeClass, AnotherClass, AndAnotherClass etc would all implement. This interface would have `getXYZ()` and `setXYZ()` on it

You could then:

```
for (SomeInterface class : SomeClassList) {
         class.getXYZ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts to this.

**First:** Create an Interface (or base class)

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    void someMethod();
}

public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass implements SomeInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Second:** You can call someMethod on a List of the **interface** (or base class)

```
public void callSomeMethod(List<SomeInterface> things) {
    for (SomeInterface someInterface : things) {
        someInterface.someMethod();
    }
}


List<SomeInterface> someInterfaceList = //make some list
callSomeMethod(someInterfaceList); //This Works!!!

List<SomeClass> someClassList = //make some list
callSomeMethod(someClassList); //This is an error :(
```

**Third:** Generics if you need to use Lists of SomeClass or SomeOtherClass

```
// I prefer the explicit type
public <T extends SomeInterface> void callSomeMethod(List<T> things) {
    for (T t : things) {
        t.someMethod();
    }
}

// This works as well
public void callSomeMethod(List<? extends SomeInterface> things) {
    for (SomeInterface t : things) {
        t.someMethod();
    }
}
```